# Problem with pushviewcontroller animation while fetching iPhone contact's image

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimage, nsdata, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to show a contact from the iPhone address book. I fetch the names and image of the contacts. Then I pass these details to Detail view.

Now the problem is when I push the detail view, the animation is very slow and choppy. This happens only when I fetch the contact detail which has image. The pushviewcontroller animation works perfectly fine when the contact detail does not contain image.

Also I noticed that this problem occurs only in iPhone 4.0. When I tested this on iPhone 3gs, it worked perfectly. So I am thinking this might be device specific problem.

I fetch the contact name in the following way:

```
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef record=ABCFindPersonMatchingPhoneNumber(addressBook,
                                                    number, 0, 0);

if(record)
{
    NSString *name=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(record);
   NSLog(@"Contact Name %@",name);

}
```

And I fetch the contact image in the following way:

```
     if (record && ABPersonHasImageData(record))
    {

        CFDataRef data;
        data = ABPersonCopyImageData(record);
        if (data)
        {
            NSLog(@"ImageFound");
            imageData=[[NSData alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)data];

        }
    }
```

Then I pass the imageData to the Detail View

```
DetailView *detail=[[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
detail.imageData=imageData
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

How can I improve on this?

Comment: Are you doing [UIImage imageWithData:imageData] inside your property setter or generally while pushing the view? Have you tried providing the DetailView with the actual image (loading the UIImage before pushing?

Comment: i tried passing the actual image to DetailView, even then the animation problem persisted. so i tried passing NSData to DetailView. but still no results. but as i said before, i come across this problem only in iphone 4.0, it works fine in iphone 3gs

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case if someone comes to this here with a related problem:
add

```
[detail view];
```

right after the initialization and before setting any @properties (`detail.imageData=imageData;`) - because the outlets of the segue are not set yet.